# change the position of prepended file inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to make the prepended file input appear below the previous element instead of above it. So that in this jquery, the "Select a file:" text remains on top of all added elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_more').click(function(){

         var current_count = $('input[type="file"]').length;
         var next_count = current_count + 1;

    $('#file_upload').prepend('<p><input type="file" name="file_' + next_count +'" /></p>');

    });
 });

 <p>Select a file: <input  name="file_1" type="file">
                   <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" ></p>
                   <a id="add_more" href="#">add more</a>
```

Comment: where is `#file_upload`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch To append :)

```
 $('#file_upload').append('<p><input type="file" name="file_' + next_count +'" /></p>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Switching to append will do what you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_more').click(function(){

         var current_count = $('input[type="file"]').length;
         var next_count = current_count + 1;

    $('#file_upload').append('<p><input type="file" name="file_' + next_count +'" /></p>');

    });
 });
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HYcxx/